# Fork inline Mysql

Tags: mysql

In mysql it is possible to make a fork in the command "SET"?

Like this:

```
UPDATE `table`.`data` SET `hits` = (`hits`-1<0 ? 0:`hits`-1) WHERE `data`.`id`='15';
```

Comment: It seems bizarre that you'd want to subtract one from id and then if the result is positive, use zero. ids are usually positive. And even stranger that you have a where clause that requires id to be 15, so you know for certain that id - 1 will not be negative. Are you sure that your pseudo code is correct?

Comment: was just an example do not worry. I put `id` by mistake, within the FORK

Comment: Because the negative vote? I can not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`IF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
UPDATE `table`.`data`
SET `hits` = IF(`id` - 1 > 0, 0, `id` - 1)
WHERE `data`.`id`='15';
```

In this specific case you could also use [`LEAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least).

```
UPDATE `table`.`data`
SET `hits` = LEAST(`id` - 1, 0)
WHERE `data`.`id`='15';
```

Your code seems wrong though. I'm almost certain that you meant to write this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET hits = GREATEST(0, hits - 1)
WHERE id = 15;
```